# Ember.js - ember new command installing project in home directory instead of current directory

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I run the `ember new` command to create a new project, the project gets created in my home directory instead of the directory the `new` command is executed from.

Anyone know why?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I'm running OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a package.json file in my root directory. Deleting it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This fixed my issue too. I'd like to understand what this package.json file is doing and how it is dictating project folder creation path.

Comment: this is the solution and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

**You have to use the `ember init` command if you want to create a new project in the current folder.**

From the docs for `init` and `new` commands (http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-ember-cli):

`ember new <project-name>` description:

> "Creates a folder called `<project-name`> and generates an application structure for you."

`ember init` description:

> "Generates an application structure for you in the current folder."

Better descriptions can be found in the source code for the `init` and `new` commands (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/18d377b264859548f41aba6c3ea2015b90978068/lib/commands/new.js and https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/18d377b264859548f41aba6c3ea2015b90978068/lib/commands/init.js):

`ember new <project-name>` description is:

> "Creates a new folder and runs `ember init` in it."

The `ember init` description is:

> "Creates a new ember-cli project in the current folder."

The relevant part of the `ember new <project-name>` code is:

```
return createAndStepIntoDirectory
  .run({
    directoryName: packageName,
    dryRun: commandOptions.dryRun
  })
  .then(initCommand.run.bind(initCommand, commandOptions, rawArgs))
  .then(gitInit.run.bind(gitInit, commandOptions, rawArgs));
```

So the `new` command creates and steps into the project directory name you pass into it and then runs `init` in that directory which generates all the ember goodness.

*Note that the `ember new <project-name>` command also creates a git repository for you (if you have set up git on your machine) but the `ember init` command does not.*

Comment: "So the new command creates and steps into the project directory name you pass into it and then runs init in that directory which generates all the ember goodness".That's what I'm saying doesn't happen. When I execute `ember new`, a new project always gets created in my home directory. So the directory specified by `ember new` never gets stepped into.

Comment: @user1866924 ahh I see...sorry, I completely misunderstood your question! At the risk of stating the obvious, have you made sure that the directory you pass into `ember new` doesn't already exist?

Comment: Yes, I've verified the directory passed into `ember new` doesn't already exist.

Comment: This is so annoying. Just updated to the latest version of ember-cli but projects are still getting created in my home directory. I also noticed that the node_modules directory is getting created outside of the directory I specify with the new command.

Comment: I see an issue has been created for this here. https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3792